# What are the differences among `require`, `import`, and `use`?

Tags: clojure

Why do we need all of `require`, `import`, and `use`?

Answer (score 69):

**Require**

[**require**](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/require) loads a Clojure library so that you can use it in your current file or REPL.

This is the normal way to access functions and definition in a Clojure library.

**Use**

[**use**](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/use) brings in a Clojure namespace in the same way as require, but in addition it *refers* to the definitions in the loaded namespace from the current namespace (i.e. it creates a convenient alias in the current namespace).

Don't over-use it (pun intended) - it can easily cause namespace conflicts!

**Import**

[**import**](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/import) is for importing Java classes and interfaces only.

```
user=> (import java.util.Date)
java.util.Date

user=> (def *now* (Date.))
#'user/*now*
```

If you don't need to interoperate with Java code then you can safely ignore import.

Comment: This question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. The referred-to answer does not explain "import". This should be the accepted answer.